# Rxjs Observables - How to drop items until some time has passed?

Tags: rxjs, observable

I am looking for a way to ignore emitted values until some time has passed. But I can only find operators that will repeat their behaviour, like throttleTime.

Something like:

```
someSubject$.dropUntilTime(5000).map()


--D-----C-----B-----A--->
--D-----C--------------->

--|----------|----------|
10000       5000        0
```

Comment: maybe things like `skipWile(Observable.timer(5000))`? just duck-typing so haven't verified it works though.

Comment: It seems to work but if you could make an answer with a bit more details I would gladly accept it.
Edit: sorry, actually it does not work, I get: this.predicate is not a function

Comment: It seems that skipUntil(Observable.timer(5000)) would work, I suppose you had that in mind.

Comment: yeah, I was writing on mobile and found 1. I meant wrong operator 2. and even misspelled it. lol. glad you found correct one.